# R software - rvest package, error in "download number"

Tags: r, rvest

I want download Amazon books review counts but I have one problem

I tried the following:

```
library(rvest)
url<-paste0("http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_4_nr_p_72_3?",
            "fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2C",
            "n%3A4%2Cp_72%3A1250224011&bbn=4&ie=UTF8&qid",
            "=1440446201&rnid=1250219011")
html<-html(url)


Reviews <- try({html_nodes(html, "#s-results-list-atf .a-text-normal:nth-child(2)") %>%
    html_text()}, silent = TRUE)
```

But I only have 4 review counts in my R console and not 12 (Using selector gadget). What did I do wrong?

When I tried to download the books' names I didn't have the same problem... only in review counts.

```
Book <- try({ html_nodes(html, ".s-access-title") %>%
                        html_text()}, silent = TRUE)
```

page link [Amazon Page](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_4_nr_p_72_3?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A4%2Cp_72%3A1250224011&bbn=4&ie=UTF8&qid=1440446201&rnid=1250219011)

Comment: What are you trying to extract? I don't see any reviews at that URL, only books

Comment: I want extract the values 168, 232, 1607, 2226, 1060, 25, 731, 2374, 345, 7205, 1134 and 1136 (number of book reviews), for example the first book "The Rabbit Who Wants To Fall Asleep: A New Way Of Getting Children To Sleep" has 168 reviews..

Comment: I got the ratings (x out of 5 stars) by: `x<-html(url) %>% html_nodes("i") %>% html_text; x[grepl("out of",x)]`.

Comment: Michael  I want the number next to the stars..

Comment: which is why that is not posted as an answer. only a nudge for the types of operations that you should be trying yourself...

Comment: you may want to actually read the Amazon Conditions of Use, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the canonical approach, but here's what I did that works:

```
#via Inspect element in Chrome, the relevant info is
#  in an <a> tag with class 'a-size-small a-link-normal a-text-normal'
#  but this does not uniquely identify the review counts
#  (e.g., the $12.00 Buy used & new... bit is also there)
#  so we take a step up and find that both the rating
#  and the review count are stored in a <div> tag
#  with class 'a-row a-spacing-mini'
x<-html(url) %>% html_nodes("div.a-row.a-spacing-mini") %>%
  html_nodes("a.a-size-small.a-link-normal.a-text-normal") %>%
  html_text
#upon inspection of x, we can see that the relevant numbers
#  always appear by themselves, thus:
> x[!is.na(as.integer(gsub(",","",x)))]

 [1] "168"   "232"   "1,607" "2,226" "1,060" "25"    "731"   "2,374" "345"   "7,205"
[11] "1,134" "1,137"
```

Comment: Many thanks Michael, you really help my.. But, you have some ideia Why do I use " Reviews <- try({html_nodes(html, "#s-results-list-atf .a-text-normal:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text()}, silent = TRUE) " It only extracted the first 4 numbers and not 12? Many thks for your help.

Comment: Amazing the explanation :)

Comment: @Kardu see edit for a slight improvement to the approach that probably gets closer to the typical application.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your time.  You help me a lot!